# Haskell list comprehension to map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, list-comprehension, concatenation

I am new to haskell . I was wondering If I can do the following thing using just map and concat ?

```
                 [ (x,y+z) | x<-[1..10], y<-[1..x], z<-[1..y] ]
```

Comment: No My experiemnts with haskell Saw this question in some excercis on haskell somewhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
concat $ concat $ map (\x -> map (\y -> map (\z -> (x,y+z)) [1..y]) [1..x]) [1..10]
```

Although the [official translation](http://haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.11) uses concatMap:

```
concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> concatMap (\z -> [(x,y+z)]) [1..y]) [1..x]) [1..10]
```